# How to get the objectName of the Item inside an QML Listview with Loader as delegate?

Tags: qt, qml

I have this Listview with an QML Loader as delegate and I would like to access the objectName of the loader.item. Important is, that the loader has no id property. The objectName shall be shown in the mytext.text.

I tried to access the objectName as shown in the example, but the mytext.text keeps empty.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: viewModel
        ListElement {
            view: "test.qml"
        }
        ListElement {
            view: "test2.qml"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: mylistview
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        spacing: 2
        model: viewModel
        delegate: Item {
            Loader {
                source: view
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: mytext
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x:0
        y:0
        text: mylistview.itemAtIndex(mylistview.currentIndex).objectName
    }

    Text {
        id: mytext2
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x:100
        y:0
        text: mylistview.currentIndex
    }
}
```

**test.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: myItem
    objectName: "redrectangle"
    color: "red"
}
```

**test2.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Rectangle {
    id: myItem
    objectName: "bluerectangle"
    color: "blue"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use children and find the item of loader or better solution is using property that hold item's name.(simpler)

```
delegate: Item {
    property string itemObjName: ld.item.objectName
    Loader {
        id:ld
        source: view
    }
}
...
text: mylistview.itemAtIndex(mylistview.currentIndex).itemObjName
```

full example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: viewModel
        ListElement {
            view: "test.qml"
        }
        ListElement {
            view: "test2.qml"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: mylistview
        anchors.fill: parent
        z:1
        spacing: 2
        model: viewModel
        delegate: Item {
            property string itemObjName: ld.item.objectName
            Loader {
                id:ld
                source: view
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: mytext
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        z:100
        text: mylistview.itemAtIndex(mylistview.currentIndex).itemObjName
        font.bold: true
    }
}
```

Comment: the hint with children was the missing point for me. Sometimes is so simple text: mylistview.currentItem.children[0].children[0].objectName

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: Highlight problem]

The issue you're having is because your Loader's properties are hidden inside the Item:

```
    delegate: Item {
        Loader { }
    }
```

If the `Item` isn't necessary, then, you can consider removing the `Item`, i.e.

```
    delegate: Loader { }
```

Else you're going to have to bubble up properties from your Loader to your parent Item (which is precisely what the accepted answer demonstrates).

[EDIT: Original DelegateChooser answer]

I made numerous improvements to your application:

- First, don't set width and height and also set anchors.fill
- Second, I use ColumnLayout for positioning and avoid absolute placement
- Define a `highlight` so you can see the current item
- Implement MouseArea so you can change the current item
- Use DelegateChooser instead of Loader - it's cleaner
- The delegates themselves were missing geometry, so I set their width and height to 200
- You can use listView.currentIndex and listView.currentItem.objectName in your Text components
- Also, I added listView.forceActiveFocus() so that it will respond to arrow key events

Here's a working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
Page {
    id: page
    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        RowLayout {
            Text {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                text: mylistview.currentIndex
            }
            Text {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                text: mylistview.currentItem.objectName
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: mylistview
            Layout.preferredWidth: 400
            Layout.preferredHeight: 400
            clip: true
            spacing: 2
            model: viewModel
            delegate: DelegateChooser {
                role: "type"
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "test"; Test1 { } }
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "test2"; Test2 { } }
            }
            highlight: Rectangle {
                border.color: "yellow"
                border.width: 5
                color: "transparent"
                z: 2
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: viewModel
        ListElement { type: "test" }
        ListElement { type: "test2" }
    }
}

// Test1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: 200
    height: 200
    objectName: "redrectangle"
    color: "red"
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            listView.currentIndex = index;
            listView.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }
}

// Test2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: 200
    height: 200
    objectName: "bluerectangle"
    color: "blue"
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            listView.currentIndex = index;
            listView.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Its good exmaple and of course its improve my example with geometry issue, but you introduced a new component and the loader is forbidden to change in my example. I cannot mark your example as solution, but is a good example with DelegateChooser

Comment: @Shazter Ok. I edit the answer and explained the visibility problem of your Loader but left my DelegateChooser answer on the bottom.